# Is there always a square between two consecutive cubes?

Tags: number-theory

Is there always a square between two consecutive cubes?

I just thought of this question. It seems really simple and the answer is probably yes.

Edit: I should have given this more than 2 seconds of thought.

Comment: What are your thoughts on this question?  What context did you encounter it in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We show that if $a^3$ and $(a+1)^3$ are two consecutive *positive* cubes, then there is a perfect square strictly between $a^3$ and $(a+1)^3$. Let $x=\sqrt{a^3}$. If $x$ is an integer, let $b=x+1$. If $x$ is not an integer, let $b=\lceil x\rceil$ (the ceiling function). We will show that $b^2\lt (a+1)^3$.

We have $b\le a^{3/2}+1$. It follows that 
$$b^2\le a^3+2a^{3/2}+1.$$
Now it is enough to show that $2a^{3/2}\le 3a^2+3a$. This is clear.

Comment: Oops I am an idiot.

Comment: The answer was clear to you. The rest was grind. Almost anything works, since after a while there are many squares between consecutive cubes. So the required inequalities were not going to give trouble.

Comment: I stupidly did not even attempt the  question. I was just not thinking properly.

Comment: Well, you attempted it, in that you undoubtedly scanned mentally the first few cubes. That is a very important first step, which I should have put down, since I did that reality check before starting to write the proof.

Answer (score 1):

We have $$(n+1)^2-n^2=2n+1$$ and $$(n+1)^3-n^3=3n^2+3n+1.$$ Let $f(x)=2x^{1\over 2}+1$ and $g(x)=3x^{2\over 3}+3x^{1\over 3}+1$. Then:

- When do we have $f(x)>g(x)$? (HINT: look at $h(x)=g(x)-f(x)=x^{1\over 3}(3x^{2\over 6}-2x^{1\over 6}+3)$.)
- So?

Answer (score 0):

We write the equation:

$$(x+1)^3-x^3=y^2$$

$$3x^2+3x+1=y^2$$

Let's use the formula.  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31118/integer-polynomials-taking-square-values/195614#195614

For these equations we use the standard approach.
For a private quadratic form:  $$y^2=ax^2+bx+1$$

Using solutions of Pell's equation:  $$p^2-as^2=1$$

Solutions can be expressed through them is quite simple.

$$y=p^2+bps+as^2$$

$$x=2ps+bs^2$$

$p,s$ - these numbers can have any sign.

Finding solutions of equations Pell - standard procedure.

So for our case. Use the Pell equation.  $p^2-3s^2=1$

And then the decision will have a look.

$$x=2ps+3s^2$$

$$y=p^2+3ps+3s^2$$

Knowing the first solution.  $( p_1 ; s_1 ) - (2 ; 1 )$

You find the following.

$$p_2=2p_1+3s_1$$

$$s_2=p_1+2s_1$$

Be aware that the number  $(p;s)$ can have any sign.

Comment: I suspect you've misunderstood the question, though this is an interesting answer to the question of 'when can the differences between two successive cubes be a square?' - that isn't what OP was asking, though...

Comment: All, I requested the author to move this answer [to another question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1390699/11619) where it is a perfect fit. Not sure whether it should be deleted here. Possibly, but I'm not gonna force the issue.